# alter page content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the next url: http://www.climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315.

It points to a youtube video, but "the google video id" can change all day, because is a url to weather forecast. Only the url above is fixed.

I am using  a digital signage software from a third party and I need create a layout to load this url.

With the software, when creating the layout I can enter the url above, and add custom html and script when the layout will be running.

I have checked with IE the source code when the url is loaded. It´s something as:

```
<html>
<title>Climatempo - Selo de Videos: SUL</title>
<body bgcolor="black" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important" >
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YPlee8K0ViE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Is possible create a javascript such as when I load the url: http://www.climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315
 it transforms this page to add "autoplay=1" as:

```
 <html>
    <title>Climatempo - Selo de Videos: SUL</title>
    <body bgcolor="black" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important" >
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YPlee8K0ViE?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I can use only javascript, no jquery.
Some help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Luiz

//////////////////
Sorry, Mr Oliver, It doesnt work. Here is the source code of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Xibo Open Source Digital Signage</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=874.31921824104" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!-- Copyright 2006-2014 Daniel Garner. Part of the Xibo Open Source Digital Signage Solution. Released under the AGPLv3 or later. -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
            #iframe {
                border: 0;
            }
            .cycle-slide p, p.cycle-slide {
                margin-bottom:0;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">

</style>
        <link href="modules/preview/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"><style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><body class="ie6"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]><body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]><body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
        <div id="content"><html>
    <title>Climatempo - Selo de Videos: SUL</title>
    <body bgcolor="black" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important" >
    <iframe id="myframe" width="420" height="315" src="http://www.climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
</body>
</html></div>
    </body>
    <script src="modules/preview/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script src="modules/preview/xibo-layout-scaler.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
function EmbedInit()
{
    // Init will be called when this page is loaded in the client.
var firstIframe = document.getElementsById("myframe");

//get the current source
var src = firstIframe.src;

//update the src with "autoplay=1"
var newSrc = src+'?autoplay=1';

//change iframe's src
firstIframe.src = newSrc;
    return;
}
</script><script type="text/javascript">   var options = {"originalWidth":"874.31921824104","originalHeight":"436.5342019544","previewWidth":"1255.6954397394104","previewHeight":"626.9495114006552","scaleOverride":0};   $(document).ready(function() { EmbedInit(); });</script>
</html>
<!--[[[CONTROLMETA]]]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
<title>Climatempo - Selo de Videos: SUL</title>
<body bgcolor="black" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important" >
<iframe id = "myFrame" width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YPlee8K0ViE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    iFrame.src = iFrame.src + '?autoplay=1';
    iFrame.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesnt work, mr Oliver, please see my post edited with more informations.  I only have src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YPlee8K0ViE after the page loaded.

Comment: So are you grabbing the contents of that page and then displaying the HTML on your page?

Comment: Originally, I have only the url http://www.climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315 to load the content. I need  access this page and make autoplay=1

Comment: Sorry, no result. I can see the youtube video, but it is stopped. No autoplay.

Comment: View the source of the iframe with your dev tools inspector and let me know what the source says

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102519/discussion-between-luiz-alves-and-oliver-queen).

Comment: sorry, but I have no access to videoid. I have a static url climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315 It´s a public service of weather forecast in Brazil. Each day, if I want see the video I need only the url and a new youtube with other video id is loaded. I need a code working only with the url above.

Answer (score 0):

So google have `IFRAME API`, but I'm not sure this will work with your software. Have you given this a thought.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements

**UPDATED** - doesn't stop after 6 seconds.

HTML :

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'YPlee8K0ViE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
```

My Code Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwOVPR

Comment: I also had the id as storing the video id as a data attribute. Then grab that before you create the iframe for the video. Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obPeoG

Comment: sorry, but I have no access to videoid. I have a static url http://www.climatempo.com.br/tempo-no-seu-site/videos/selo/sul/420x315  It´s a public service of weather forecast in Brazil. Each day, if I want see the video I need only the url and a new youtube with other video id is loaded. I need a code working only with the url above.

Comment: @LuizAlves I thought you had the option to grab it directly from YouTube. I'm sorry, let me see if I can come up with a different solution for you.